# ¿Puedo usar json como una base de datos?

Tags: javascript, json

resulta que estoy realizando un pagina web con unos artiuculos definidos ya. Pero claro esta que no voy a crear una interfaz por cada articulo manualmente. Queria saber si al crear un json con los articulos y generar una vista a partir de ello, se podria subir la pagina normal y ser publicada? o los hositings o dominios no soportan json?

Comment: De poder se puede @Daniel Felipe Aristizabal pero mejor que uses una base de datos.

Comment: json es un formato de archivo.. o de cadena de texto.. no tiene nada que ver con que sea soportado o no...

Comment: Las bases de datos se llaman así por algo, y sus motores estan optimizados para tratar los datos.  Si prefieres usar json es tu decisión, y es posible, pero te encontrarás limitado si necesitas hacer consultas o actualizaciones al mismo que con una base de datos ya te viene dado, pues tendras que escribir tu propio engine de manipulación del json. Las respuestas a esta pregunta estarán basadas en opiniones, como la mia, y no cumpliran con un propósito específico ni un problema concreto de código/error, y es probable que termine cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

JSON es un fichero. No hay ningún problema en usar como repositorio de datos un fichero JSON siempre y cuando sea de sólo lectura.

Lo que yo sí te aconsejaría es que crearas algún tipo de módulo que sirviera esa información para que si posteriormente quieres cambiarlo a otro tipo de almacenamiento se pueda hacer sólo cambiando dicho módulo.